# why isn't my GUI working?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm just wondering what error i've made that means my GUI isn't working. What it's meant to do is open up a window with 3 buttons and when you click those buttons it opens a new GUI - so obviously for Customer register, it opens a registration page. Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Customer login", width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Customer register", width = 25, command = self.new_window2)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Driver login", width = 25, command = self.new_window3)
        self.button3.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Login(self.newWindow)

    def new_window2(self):
        self.newWindow2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app2 = CustReg(self.newWindow2)

    def new_window3(self):
        self.newWindow3 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app3 = DriverLog(self.newWindow3)

class Login:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.newL = tk.Label(self.master, text = "username", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.newL.pack()
        self.newT = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.newT.pack()
        self.secL = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Password", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.secL.pack()
        self.secT = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.secT.pack()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Log in', width = 25, command = self.master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()


class CustReg:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your desired username", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label.pack()
        self.TextU = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextU.pack()
        self.Label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your desired password", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label2.pack()
        self.TextP = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextP.pack()
        self.Label3 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your email address", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label3.pack()
        self.TextE = tk.Tex(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextE.pack()
        self.Label4 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your pick up address", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label4.pack()
        self.TextPick = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextPick.pack()
        self.frame.pack()



class DriverLog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.gg = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Log in", height = 2, width = 25, command = self.master.destroy)
        self.gg.pack()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Login(root)
    app2 = CustReg(root)
    app3 = DriverLog(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Other than the typo ``tk.Tex`` that should be ``tk.Text``?

Comment: changing that loads the register account and log in page - but not the main window with all the buttons. https://gyazo.com/779c04ae268b3db9c7eb44800d7a76cd is what shows but not what i want to show as the first window

Comment: What is the code in your question currently doing—i.e. how is it not working incorrectly—and what would you like it to do instead?

Comment: This question lacks a question. You can't just dump a hundred lines of code and ask "Why doesn't this do what I expect it to do?" First define what you expect it to do, then build a minimal example that shows the behavior you're experiencing, then post that minimal example.

Comment: @martineau https://gyazo.com/779c04ae268b3db9c7eb44800d7a76cd is what it's currently doing and what I want it to do is above the code. It just isn't loading the first window (with the 3 options) and instead just loading the CustReg and login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, what about this code in the main method

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It seems closer to what you want to achieve. It opens up a window and the first button opens the log in window, the second opens the customer register window, the third opens another log in window (Driver Login)

Full code

```
import tkinter as tk
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Customer login", width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Customer register", width = 25, command = self.new_window2)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Driver login", width = 25, command = self.new_window3)
        self.button3.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Login(self.newWindow)

    def new_window2(self):
        self.newWindow2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app2 = CustReg(self.newWindow2)

    def new_window3(self):
        self.newWindow3 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app3 = DriverLog(self.newWindow3)

class Login:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.newL = tk.Label(self.master, text = "username", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.newL.pack()
        self.newT = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.newT.pack()
        self.secL = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Password", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.secL.pack()
        self.secT = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.secT.pack()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Log in', width = 25, command = self.master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()


class CustReg:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your desired username", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label.pack()
        self.TextU = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextU.pack()
        self.Label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your desired password", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label2.pack()
        self.TextP = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextP.pack()
        self.Label3 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your email address", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label3.pack()
        self.TextE = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextE.pack()
        self.Label4 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Enter your pick up address", height = 1, width = 25)
        self.Label4.pack()
        self.TextPick = tk.Text(self.master, height = 1, width = 25)
        self.TextPick.pack()
        self.frame.pack()



class DriverLog:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.gg = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Log in", height = 2, width = 25, command = self.master.destroy)
        self.gg.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Oohh, almost there :D https://gyazo.com/6d21fa751e38b27bd486900383473e69 is what is being show now, I just need to get rid of the bit below the 3 buttons. I only input what you gave me, haven't changed anything else

Comment: To me it shows correctly only one window, I posted the full code